# Solving for the superconducting gap energy integral

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to solve the integral for the superconducting gap energy in Mathematica as described in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54200/superconducting-gap-temperature-dependence-how-to-calculate-this-integral):

$$
\eta\approx\int_{0}^{\delta^{-1}\sinh\eta}\tanh\left(0.882\frac{\delta}{\tau}\sqrt{1+z^2}\right)\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}
$$

$\eta$ is a known value depending on the materials, $0\le\delta=\Delta(T)/\Delta_0\le1$ and $0\le\tau=T/T_c\le1$ are dimensionless numbers. I want to find $\delta$ as a function of $\tau$. The author of the original post mentioned that I can fix $\delta$ and solve for $\tau$ for different values of $\delta$, but I don't know the script to make this work in Mathematica. `Solve` and `NSolve` do not work for me.

```
Solve[n == 
  Integrate[
   Tanh[0.882 d/0.1 Sqrt[1 + z^2]]*1/Sqrt[1 + z^2], {z, 0, 
    Sinh[n/d}], d]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
η = 1;
int[δ_?NumberQ, τ_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Tanh[882/1000*δ/τ*Sqrt[1 + z^2]]/Sqrt[1 + z^2], {z, 0, Sinh[η]/δ}]
ContourPlot[η - int[δ, τ] == 0, {τ, 0.001, 1}, {δ, 0.001, 1}, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]